# I have memory leak when execute this C code in Ubuntu

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, memory-leaks

After pass for this function I have memory leaks.

```
void downloadFile(int sockfd) {


FILE *f;
   char *buff;
   int err, len = 0;
   char fitxer[STR_BASE];

   // Demanem a l'usuari el nom del fitxer a descarregar
   printf("Introdueix el nom del fitxer que vols descarregar (amb extensió incluida!): ");
   __fpurge(stdin);
   scanf("%[^\n]",fitxer);
   len = strlen(fitxer);

   // Si introdueix una cadena buida insistim...
   while(len<=0) {
      printf("Introdueix el nom del fitxer que vols descarregar (amb extensió incluida!): ");
      __fpurge(stdin);
      scanf("%[^\n]",fitxer);
      len = strlen(fitxer);
   }

   // Establim el final del string
   fitxer[strlen(fitxer)] = '\0';

   // Passem la llargada de la cadena a enviar
   write(sockfd, &len, sizeof(int));

   // Passem la cadena
   write(sockfd, &fitxer, len);

   // Guardem el fitxer
   read(sockfd, &err, sizeof(int));
   if (err==FILE_NOT_EXIST) {
      printf("***El fitxer indicat no existeix al directori!\n");
   } else {
      // Creem o concatenem un fitxer amb el nom del arxiu a descarregar
      f = fopen(fitxer,"a");
      len = 0;

      // Anem llegint bytes del servidor fins arribar al final del fitxer a descarregar
      read(sockfd, &len, sizeof(int));
      while (len > 0) {
         /* Natejem la cadena....
         for (int i = 0; i<MAX; i++) {
            buff[i] = '\0';
         }
         */
         buff = malloc((sizeof(char) * len) + 1);
         // Llegim els caracters a grabar
         read(sockfd, buff, len);
         //buff[strlen(buff)] = '\0';
         printf("BUFF = %s / LEN = %d\n",buff, len);

         // Grabem els caracters al fitxer
         fputs(buff, f);
         read(sockfd, &len, sizeof(int));
      }

      // Tanquem el fitxer
      fclose(f);
      printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
   }
}
```

As you can see it is a step from a file through a server socket to the client, in the server I do not see any garbage left but in the client once the function is executed, if I execute it again returns strange characters:

```
BUFF = #include <w�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = sys/types.w�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = h>
#incluw�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = de <sys/sow�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = cket.h>
#w�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = include <sw�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = tdio.h>
#w�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = include <sw�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = tring.h>
w�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = #include <w�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = netinet/inw�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = .h>
#inclw�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = ude <arpa/w�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = inet.h>
#w�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = include <uw�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = nistd.h>
w�1 / LEN = 10
BUFF = #include <w�1 / LEN = 10
w�1 / LEN = 10>
BUFF = 
{w�1 / LEN = 1
```

Comment: Your code has a call to malloc but no call to free. So yes, if that's all you have, it will leak.

Comment: When i call free function the program fails ... Can you pass me an example with my code of call to free function

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Oh my goodness, finally i really can fix my code, a lot of thanks Mat!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `free(buff);`, otherwise you have a leak.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Like mat says, the error is in the absence of free function. Now i fixed the problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There are really numerous errors in your code. Let's look at a few:

```
   char fitxer[STR_BASE];

   printf("Introdueix el nom del fitxer que vols descarregar (amb extensió incluida!): ");
   __fpurge(stdin);
   scanf("%[^\n]",fitxer);
   len = strlen(fitxer);
```

And why would `len` have any meaningful value? Note that `fitxer`is uninitialized, so if `scanf` fails it will contain garbage and so `strlen` may find a zillion characters before encoutering a null. You should have checked the return value from `scanf`

```
  // Establim el final del string
  fitxer[strlen(fitxer)] = '\0';
```

Interesting.... You want to terminate the string and to do that you look for the terminating null character. Note that `strlen` will traverse the string from the first character *until it encounters a null character*. (So if strlen finds a null character, the string was already terminated, and if the string isn't terminated, then strlen is the wrong way to find its length.)

```
   read(sockfd, &err, sizeof(int));
   if (err==FILE_NOT_EXIST) {
```

Here you read an integer into `err` and then want to know if the value you have read equals `FILE_NOT_EXIST`? I don't understand that logic. Is that your server's response? Are the bytes of an int in the same order on your server and your client, called **endianness**? But if you want to know if `read` was successful you must check if it returns the number of bytes you expect and if not, check `errno` for the cause. You should check that will all reads.

```
     read(sockfd, buff, len);
     //buff[strlen(buff)] = '\0';
```

Here too you must check the return value of `read`. And the line you commented out is important, but incorrect, assuming what you recieve is indeed a string and not binary data. It should be:

```
     if (read(sockfd, buff, len)!=len) ...// error
     buff[len] = '\0';
```

As others noted, you must release the memory you got from `malloc` when no longer needed:

```
    free(buff);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, really, I am starting to learn c and all the answers and corrections I can provide are welcome, thanks again! I trying to fix all code errors...